# Substracting time values in Excel XML

Tags: xml, excel

I'm trying to substract two times and obtain the value in hours.

Hurdles:

- it would seem that I need to specify a full date, that I cannot simply use a time?
- in another example, if I use a full date (ie. 2014-08-22T08:30:00), in Excel I see "41875.35" in the cell instead of the date

Here is my current markup:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ss:Workbook xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet">
    <ss:Worksheet ss:Name="Sheet1">
        <ss:Table>
            <ss:Row>
                <ss:Cell>
                    <ss:Data ss:Type="DateTime">08:30:00</ss:Data>
                </ss:Cell>
            </ss:Row>
            <ss:Row>
                <ss:Cell>
                    <ss:Data ss:Type="DateTime">17:30:00</ss:Data>
                </ss:Cell>
            </ss:Row>
            <ss:Row>
                <ss:Cell ss:Formula="=INT((R[-1]C-R[-2]C)*24)"></ss:Cell>
            </ss:Row>
        </ss:Table>
    </ss:Worksheet>
</ss:Workbook>
```

Errors I'm getting:

```
XML ERROR in Table
REASON: Bad Value
FILE:   C:\timediff.xml.xls
GROUP:  Cell
TAG:    Data
VALUE:  08:30:00

XML ERROR in Table
REASON: Bad Value
FILE:   C:\timediff.xml.xls
GROUP:  Cell
TAG:    Data
VALUE:  17:30:00
```

**Update #1**

Latest cut:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ss:Workbook xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet">
    <ss:Worksheet ss:Name="Sheet1">
        <ss:Table>
            <ss:Row>
                <ss:Cell>
                    <ss:Data ss:Type="String">08:30</ss:Data>
                </ss:Cell>
            </ss:Row>
            <ss:Row>
                <ss:Cell>
                    <ss:Data ss:Type="String">17:30</ss:Data>
                </ss:Cell>
            </ss:Row>
            <ss:Row>
                <ss:Cell ss:Formula="=round((timevalue(R[-1]C) - timevalue(R[-2]C)) *24, 1)"></ss:Cell>
            </ss:Row>
        </ss:Table>
    </ss:Worksheet>
</ss:Workbook>
```

Problem persists that once in Excel, changing 08:30 to 08:15, the formula will indicate an error: #VALUE!.

Comment: You're using XML, so your time values are not numbers.  You should treat them as strings.  Excel will parse them as the correct value.

Comment: @jbarker2160 it works for the initial load in Excel. After that, any manual modifications to the times will result in the formula not updating and the appending of ":00" to times thus changing their alignment. Any ideas?

Comment: You should really use the TIMEVALUE function.  It's an extra step in the process, but Excel really sucks at dealing with time values.

Comment: @jbarker2160 I used timevalue() and it seems to work still. However, changing any of the values (ie: 08:30 to 08:15) will create an error #VALUE!

Comment: It seems that the problem is in how you're changing the values, but without know ing exactly how you're doing that I can't really help you.

Comment: @jbarker2160 copy and paste my latest cut into file.xsl, load into Excel, modify 08:30 for 08:15 and the formula will complain.

Comment: How do you modify the formula?  What is the starting formula?  What is the ending formula?  I've never had issues with using this function.

Comment: @jbarker2160 my latest example will show 3 cells: time 1, time 2 and difference. The formula is in the XML already and implemented in the 3rd cell, no need to do anything. Simply change the first time from 08:30 to 08:15 and notice Excel complain. Don't know how else to explain this.

Comment: You're ignoring data types.  When you edit the value in the cell, Excel parses it to a numeric time value.  `TIMEVALUE` expects a string in the proper format.

Comment: If I omit the timevalue functions, it works...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Final solution:

```
ss:Formula="=ROUND( ((R[-1]C-R[-2]C) * 24) - 0.5, 3)
```